# Error:Could not build wheels for pycryptodome, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, firebase, flask, nosql, pyrebase

I am trying to install pyrebase to make use of the authentication and cloud service, but when I `pip install pyrebase`I get this error.

Could not build wheels for pycryptodome, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Looking on the web, I found that I should install `pycryptodome` which if I can install but still presents the same error, I found in other forums that the solution was to install `Pyrebase4`, but when I run it tells me that there is no such module

What steps should I follow to install pyrebase in my python 3.10.11?